# Enhance loop in java not working in IDE. how to make it work?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am currently learning java in Eclipse IDE. and I used enhanced loop in a simple program and it is showing error.  here is the code

```
public final class enhancedFor {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int jatin[]={4,5,6,7,8};
        int total=0;
        for (int x: jatin){
            total+=x;

        }
        System.out.println(total);

    }

}
```

It is showing error where I have declared the for loop.
" for each is only available if source level is 1.5 or greater."

Comment: what is your java version & change your compiler version

Comment: consider writing `int[]  jatin` instead of `int jatin[]`, brackets at the variable is usually discouraged: https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s4.8.3.2-array-declarations

Comment: Your JDK is very old. Consider JDK7 or JDK8.

Answer (score 2):

Go to project properties and correct the compiler version:

[image]

You may need to upgrade your Java too.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. If you don't mind, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] jatin = {4,5,6,7,8};

for (int x=0;x<jatin.length;x++) {
    total+=jatin[x];        
}
```

this would fix your code.